# Tokenbased Userdata in Angular with Laravel Backend

Tags: angular, laravel, token

I have the following problem.

I have a `backend` that saves my users. The whole thing was done with `Laravel`. I send a token, which I get after a successful login, to a method. This gives me back you user data. In `Postman` that works perfectly.

When I log in via my `frontend`, I get the token and save it in the localstorage. I even get the right user. And when I log out, I delete the token. Now, I log in with another user and get back the data from the first login.

I use passport.

Here is my code:

userController

```
public function userDetails()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return response()->json(['persons' => $user], 200);
    }
```

api.php

```
Route::post('userLogin', 'UserController@userLogin');
Route::post('userRegister', 'UserController@userRegister');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::post('userDetails', 'UserController@userDetails');
});
```

Angular Frontend:

```
  getUserDetail() {
    console.log('getUserDetail');
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('userToken'));
    console.log('HTTP OPTION');
    console.log(this.httpOptions);
    return this.http.post(
      this.rootUrl + '/userDetails',
      null,
      this.httpOptions
    );

  }
```

https://github.com/TheSlowlySnail/Inventory_FE

Comment: You post to a post route without a body, why not send a GET request? I know Laravel can be annoying when you're declaring post routes and don't inject the necessary parameters in your function headers. Plus, strictly speaking, POST requests are for creating data. Not retrieving it.

Comment: I do not remember why I did a POST. I made a GET out of it and get the following message: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for EditUserComponent: (?, [object Object], [object Object]).

I give the following header and no body: httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('userToken')}`
    })
  };

Comment: Now it's starting to throw errors in code you haven't posted (EditUserComponent) so that's pretty hard to debug.

Comment: That's right, sorry. https://github.com/TheSlowlySnail/Inventory_FE/blob/master/src/app/edit-user/edit-user.component.ts